# How we can use query string in asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to edit a database record on edit button ,i redirect to next page with id.
Now i am in vain to get the id from url link and i want to edit the record on this id bases how can i use this id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an action link with the Id:

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
    </td>
```

This is usually done in an overview page or something like this.
And in your Controller you need a matching Edit method like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // Do your staff and return your edit view..
    }
```

Happy Coding!